# FindShortestPath with VertexWeight

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a weighted graph on which I want to perform some `FindShortestPath` calculations. However, the problem is that my weights are defined for vertices with `VertexWeight`, but `FindShortestPath` can only use edge weights defined with `EdgeWeight`. For example, if I have a simple grid graph

```
g = GridGraph[{2, 2}, VertexWeight -> {1, 2, 1, 1}, VertexLabels -> "VertexWeight"]
```

and I compute the shortest path between the lower left and the upper right corner

```
FindShortestPath[g, 1, 4]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4}
> ```

it would give me the path over the upper left vertex which is not what I want, because this vertex has a bigger weight than the vertex in the opposite corner. How can I calculate the shortest path with regard to vertex weights?

Comment: Maybe you can construct the [line graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LineGraph.html) of `g` to get a edge-weighted graph for `FindShortestPath` to work.

Comment: @Silvia Can you explain how to do it with Mathematica? You can post it as an answer.

Comment: Define your edge weights as the sums of the corresponding pairs of vertex weights.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think this will be problematic if I start the path at a vertex with a big weight and want to move to the adjacent vertex with a small weight, the algorithm will not choose the direct path between them.

Comment: @shrx: Assuming your start and end vertices are known in advance, you can fix Daniel's proposal by subtracting half the initial vertex weight from all edges emanating from it, and subtract half the end vertex weight from all edges emanating from it. That way, the first and last vertex weights aren't counted.

Comment: I do not see the issue. If you define edge weights by thatn summing, then every initial segment contains the initial vertex weight and so that part is a wash. Likewise for the terminating vertex weight and final segment. Another way to view it as this: every path will have weight equal to twice the weights of the intermediate vertices, plus the (constant) sum of the start and end weights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from the graph indicated.

```
vertexWeight={1, 2, 1, 1};
g = GridGraph[{2, 2}, VertexWeight -> vertextWeight, 
  VertexLabels -> "VertexWeight"]
m = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
{l1, l2} = Dimensions[m];
h = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[
  Table[m[[i, j]] (vertexWeight[[i]] + vertexWeight[[j]]), {i, l1}, {j, 
     l2}] /. Rule[0, \[Infinity]], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
sp=FindShortestPath[h, 1, 4]
(*{1, 3, 4}*)
HighlightGraph[h, PathGraph[FindShortestPath[h, 1, 4]], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Dashed"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, with the illustration I can see now that @DanielLichtblau's suggestion will work even in those cases that looked problematic to me. I forgot to account that the vertex' weight would influence all edges connected to it.

Comment: In line 2 there is the misspelling 'VertextWeight'.